# safari and firefox does not send cookie when send http request to remote server with the same sub domain name but chrome does

Tags: firefox, cookies, safari

I have two servers, a.example.com and b.example.com

1. The cookie with domain .example.com was set in a.example.com/admin
2. I visit a.example.com/admin page, and in this page, a http request was send to b.example.com
3. I had a packet capture and just found that the cookie was not send when I use safari and firefox browser, but in chrome, the cookie was send.

so I was wondering way this happen, and does there exist any method by which the safari and firefox can send the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, it may help you figure this out: https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/webextension-xmlhttprequest-issues-no-cookies-or-referrer-solved/11224/15

It seems that either you need to enable 'third party cookies' or you need to wrap XMLHttpRequest. Also, make sure the website is listed in the permissions section of your manifest file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions